# inheritance class how to use the __new__ function of the bass class in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.x, inheritance classes use the `__new__` function, or its own? In the following code, two `__new__` function, how to call them?

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls):
        print("A",cls)
        return super().__new__(cls)

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        print(cls)
        return super().__new__(cls)


a = A()
print("-----------")
b = B()
```

output :

```
A <class '__main__.A'>
-----------
<class '__main__.B'>
A <class '__main__.B'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be a slight different.
First of all, since A doesn't inheriet from any class, there's no point in writing `super().__new__(cls)`. `Super()` returns the immidiate parent class. Secondely, the "this" argument in Python is usually called `self`.

Anyway, are you sure that you meant `__new__` and not `__init__`? [See the difference here](https://dev.to/pila/constructors-in-python-init-vs-new-2f9j).

```
class A:
    def __new__(self):
        print("A",self)
        return super().__new__(self)

class B(A):
    def __new__(self):
        print(self)
        return super().__new__(self)


a = A()
print("-----------")
b = B()
```

Let's look at the output:

```
A <class '__main__.A'>
-----------
<class '__main__.B'>
A <class '__main__.B'>
```

When you create A, you call only A's constructor.
When you create B, you first print class B's flag and then call A's constructor (with the `super()` function).